# Add Json file out of projects

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to separate my json settings files from my projects. Here is the hierarchy of my solution :

[image]

But `/src` and `/settings/Development` are both virtuals folders only existing in Visual Studio.

Here is the physical hierarchy of my solution :

[image]

From there, I'm trying to add these json files with a configuration builder :

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            /* PATH/TO/MY/SOLUTION/BaseTemplate (project name) */
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("SwaggerSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

But `env.ContentRootPath` gives me the path for my project, not my solution. Unfortunately my json settings files are out of my projects and I would like to keep them where they are.

I tried to add something like `Path.Join("..", env.ContentRootPath)` but I got the following error :

> System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute.

How can I add these json settings files ?

Comment: If you try to use the absolute path which  json settings files in your computer,can it work?

Comment: Yes, it works, but it will only works on my local machine unfortunately